# Site Activity and VoteGraph 20160614 in the last 12 weeks

Tags: discussion, statistics

According to http://data.stackexchange.com/webapps/query/161411/site-activity-and-votegraph the number of question votes in week was incresed almost 4 times. Is this correct?

[image: Site Activity and VoteGraph]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In taking a closer look, nothing nefarious is going on.

Since it's impossible to know someone's motivations for voting, I am going to err on the conservative side and assume that people are rewarding good posts only on their merit.  However, with badges in play, there is always a chance that people will "hunt" them.

Good content should always be recognized and rewarded, and I think we have a strong (but small) corps of users who follow that tenet.  More voting is almost always good, but having discerning voters is even better.

Comment: Just found on the users page that we have a new user that is very active as voter.

Comment: maybe the user doesn't want the content to be automatically removed.

Comment: @Rubén Jeff Atwood has said before that everyone should be using their 40 votes per day.. so by that logic, everyone should be an active voter :) (although, appropriately, of course!)

Comment: @TimMalone Stack Overflow and Web Applications can't really be compared in terms of new content per day :)

Comment: Haha, good point. Either way, I tend to try to vote a lot on good Q's and A's (probably even more so on Qs), but it is rare for me to get to the limit unless I've gone off down a rabbit hole of reading and learning or something.